# Retag-request: merge drip and drip-coffee (completed)

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I see two tags that seem to be synonymous:

- [drip](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drip)
- [drip-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drip-coffee)

I can't think of any use of "drip" that's on-topic here that would not be identical to "drip-coffee".

Edits:

- As @Robert says below, the right way is merge/rename/delete to have only one tag.
- removed this ill considered aside... <strike>Meta-meta: should *any* tag on Coffee.SE contain the string "coffee"?</strike>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is actually called "drip brewing", so I would just rename the tag(s) to [drip-brew](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drip-brew). No synonym needed; text completion will help users find the proper tag: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> → <kbd>drip-brew</kbd>

Meta-meta answer: I didn't actually have a problem with using the word "coffee" in a tag… assuming that was the proper nomenclature for that particular process. Calling it something else would not help improve clarity, but we don't have a tag called "french press coffee" or "moka coffee", so in this case, the point is somewhat moot.

Comment: Agreed; merging/renaming is what I should have said, and is the right thing in this case; but the meta-tag is currently [meta-tag:tag-synonyms], so that's the word I (mis-)used. +1 for [tag:drip-brew] to be the only (and replace all) `drip.*` tag(s); who makes these happen? Meta-agreed also on the tags containing the word "coffee" -- the current ones seem to make sense.